# Access a control's property in an aspx page from another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 aspx pages, the aspx page, say page1.aspx contains a list view and the code is as follows

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"
              GroupItemCount="3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%">
            <tr id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></td>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:Image ID="productImage" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' runat="server"/>
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="ProductTitleLinkButton"
                 runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductTitle") %>'
                 OnClick="ProductTitleLinkButton_Click"
                 PostBackUrl="~/ItemDetails.aspx">
            </asp:LinkButton>
            <br />Rs. 
            <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
            <br />        
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
        <tr runat="server">
            <td colspan="3"><hr /></td>
        </tr>
    </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here I am try to access the `DataSourceId` property of `ListView1` listview control, `ImageUrl` property of `productImage` image control and `Text` property of `ProductTitleLinkButton` Link button control from another aspx page.

The code of second aspx page, say page2.aspx is as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Checking if itemsView page exists
    if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        //Getting the list view in previous page
        ListView listView_PreviousPage = (ListView)PreviousPage.FindControl("ListView1");

        //Getting the data source of list view in the previous page
        string dataSource = listView_PreviousPage.DataSourceID;

        //Getting the SQL data source used by the list view in the previous page
        SqlDataSource sqlDataSource_PreviousPage = (SqlDataSource)PreviousPage.FindControl(dataSource);

        //Getting the SelectCommand property (to get the query) of the SQL Data source
        string selectCommand = sqlDataSource_PreviousPage.SelectCommand;

        //Getting the image of the product selected in itemsView page
        Image productImage_PreviousPage = (Image)PreviousPage.FindControl("productImage");

        //Getting the image url of the image
        string imageUrl_PreviousPage = productImage_PreviousPage.ImageUrl;
    }
}
```

I am using `FindControl()` to find the control of the previous page. But I am getting an `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Please help me out. i want the values of the properties of the controls in previous page.

Comment: Typically you will expose control values through public properties when using [PreviousPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It is not working, I have tried exposing the control values

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're clicking from one page to the next. I'd suggest handling the next button click and copying the control values to session() or passing them along in the request for the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Is your page inside a container (master page) ?

If yes, the FindControl method finds controls in the current naming container. If the control you are looking for is inside another control (typically, inside a template), you must first get a reference to the container and then search the container to find the control you want to get.

So, if page1.aspx is contained inside a master page, then get a reference to the master page in page2.aspx like below:

```
var previousPageMaster = PreviousPage.Master;
```

Then get a reference to the contentplaceholder in which the listview is contained:

```
var maincontentplaceholder = previousPageMaster.FindControl("maincontent");
```

And then you should be able to get the reference to the ListView in the ItemDetails page:

```
var listView_PreviousPage = (ListView)maincontentplaceholder.FindControl("ListView1");
```

Check the link for more information,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx