# Open a URL and pre-fill a textbox in an ASPX page from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

So what I'm doing is a little different than this:

[Access a control's property in an aspx page from another aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311954/access-a-controls-property-in-an-aspx-page-from-another-aspx-page)

because what I'm trying to do is "push" a value forward to the next page rather than "pull" it from the previous page.

What I need to do is open a new page from within an Intranet website application (actually, the page will have been previously used by the user) and pre-fill a textbox.

Can this be done?  I'm currently forwarding to the new page using:

```
String SUrl = "frmAuditSearch.aspx";
Server.Transfer(SUrl, true);
```

What I also need to do is fill a textbox called txtAuditID on frmAuditSearch.aspx with the AuditID from the current page I'm on.

And yes, I know I can use something like:

```
String SUrl = "frmAuditSearch.aspx?AuditID = '" + MyAuditID + "'";
Server.Transfer(SUrl, true);
```

but I'm trying to avoid that because most of the time there's no AuditID and that'd require tinkering with too much code.

Comment: I'd go with what you've suggested. The fact that most of the time there's no AuditID seems fine to me. Why do you see it as a problem?

Comment: Can you have a page that sometimes has a parameter and sometimes doesn't?  i.e. sometimes the URL would be frmAuditSearch.aspx?AuditID=3 and sometimes it'd be just frmAuditSearch.aspx.  How do you account for the parameter being there sometimes and not other times?

Comment: If you just want to avoid when ` MyAuditId` is null, then you can store `MyAuditID` in session and then when you want to use it just check if it has value or not.

Comment: `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("AuditID"){//do something}`

Comment: You just pass AuditID in ***QueryString***. Then use ***Response.Redirect***, and retrieve the AuditID at AuditSearch.aspx. It seems like very basic in ASP.Net Web Form, unless I'm missing something in OP.

Comment: Yes. You can. Definitely. e.g. bing.com/search?q=blah vs bing.com/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'd want to fill the text box with something like this.

```
txtAuditID.Text = (Request["AuditID"] ?? String.Empty).ToString().
```

This allows the absence of the parameter if needed

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for this!